# Zend Config Ini - Cannot parse array

Tags: ini, zend-framework

I cannot get the value of an array in an ini file.

Here's the ini file:

```
module.name = Core
module.version = 1
module.package = 'Core Modules'

module.dependency[] = Dep1
module.dependency[] = Dep2
module.dependency[] = Dep3
```

Here's the code I use to parse it:

```
$ini = new Zend_Config_Ini('/path/to/module.ini');
```

The following works fine:

```
echo $ini->module->name;
```

This, however, causes an error ('Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object'):

```
$ini->module->dependency->toArray();
```

Also, this returns null:

```
var_dump($ini->module->dependency);
```

If I change the ini file to:

```
module.name = Core
module.version = 1
module.package = 'Core Modules'

dependency[] = Dep1
dependency[] = Dep2
dependency[] = Dep3
```

I can access the array by using:

```
$ini->dependency->toArray();
```

I want the 'module.' prefix, however, because other config data will be in the file.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

You should specify a section in the top of the config. Something like this:

```
[production]
module.dependency[] = Dep1
module.dependency[] = Dep2
module.dependency[] = Dep3
```

Now this will do ok:

```
$ini = new Zend_Config_Ini('/path/to/module.ini', 'production');
$ini->module->dependency->toArray();
```